# Implementing ShaderEffect.IsEnabled

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create `ShaderEffect`'s (quite successfully tbh), however, I have an issue to properly implement `IsEnabled` for them.

I'd prefer to have `IsEnabled` to dynamically turn effect on/off, instead of changing `Effect` property of element. Mainly because I have problems with binding in animation (could explain, if someone will insist, what `IsEnabled` a **wrong** way) and usability (binding to `IsEnabled` is way easier than setting `Effect`).

Here is effect

```
public class SomeEffect : ShaderEffect
{
    public Brush Input
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(InputProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InputProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InputProperty =
        ShaderEffect.RegisterPixelShaderSamplerProperty("Input", typeof(SomeEffect), 0);

    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsEnabledProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(SomeEffect), new PropertyMetadata(true, OnIsEnabledPropertyChanged));
    private static void OnIsEnabledPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue != e.OldValue)
            (d as SomeEffect).SetValue(IsEnabledPrivateProperty, (bool)e.NewValue ? 1.0 : 0.0);
    }
    private static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledPrivateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsEnabledPrivate", typeof(double), typeof(SomeEffect), new PropertyMetadata(1.0, OnIsEnabledPrivatePropertyChanged));
    private static void OnIsEnabledPrivatePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue != e.OldValue)
            (d as SomeEffect).SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, (double)e.NewValue != 0);
        PixelShaderConstantCallback(0)(d, e);
    }

    private static PixelShader _shader = new PixelShader() { UriSource = new Uri("...", UriKind.Relative) };

    public SomeEffect()
    {
        PixelShader = _shader;
        UpdateShaderValue(IsEnabledPrivateProperty);
    }
}
```

and here is shader

```
sampler2D _input : register(s0);
float _enabled : register(C0);

float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR
{
    float4 color = tex2D(_input, uv);
    if(_enabled == 0)
        return color;

    ...
    return somethingelse;
}
```

It's done pretty stupid, shader is called always, but will do nothing (return original color) if `IsEnabled` is set.

There is a tricky workaround to have `bool` property, shader can only have `double`, so I implement another dependency property, which is then used by service functions of `ShaderEffect` (namely,  by `PixelShaderConstantCallback` and `UpdateShaderValue`). I could use converter and have `double` property, but it's better to have `bool IsEnabled` to use directly in xaml.

What I've tried:

- I tried to set `PixelShader` property to `null`, this cause service functions to fail, as they assume it will be initialized to not `null`. If some bound to static callback property of effect is set, while `PixelShader == null`, there will be an exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll
>   Additional information: PixelShader must be set on ShaderEffect.

- I did it in that stupid way I explained above. I've know very little about shaders, but it's obvious, this approach is wrong. It works however.
- I could think what it might be possible to create a custom control, which will contain two content containers: with effect (always on) and without. Changing `IsEnabled` for this control will *move* content from one container to another. But even without starting this looks pretty dumb and limited, though more optimal than previous solution (as shader will not be called for zero-sized or invisible element I think).

So, what will the **right** way to implement `IsEnabled` for `ShaderEffect`?

Comment: Custom control consisting from 2 `ContentControl`, one with effect and another without - seems to be easiest and most convenient solution. Until someone will find a better one. I also *tried* to use behavior, but failed.